# Как определить место выполнения JS скрипта на странице?

Tags: javascript, jquery

В середину страницы встроен скрипт в теге `<script>`. Можно ли как-то определить  родителя, в котором находится тег `<script>`?

Comment: Конечно можно...А что именно не получается?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Нашел решение
`document.scripts[document.scripts.length - 1].parentNode`

Comment: А если на странице 10 тегов script, каким образом собираешься определять нужный?

Comment: решение работает

Comment: Вот ссылка https://codepen.io/Vasiliy_miass/pen/yQoXXN на решение, нету никаких идентификационных данных типа id, src и все работает. Пишите свои замечания поправим что-нибудь вместе

Answer (score 1):

Если код определения находится в самом скрипте, то достаточно воспользоваться элементом [document.currentScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/currentScript):

```html
<div id="div1"><script>console.log(document.currentScript.parentNode.id);</script></div>
<div id="div2"><script>console.log(document.currentScript.parentNode.id);</script></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var script = document.getElementsByTagName("script");

for (var i = 0; i < script.length; i++) {
  if (script[i].getAttribute('src') == '#') {
    console.log(script[i].parentNode);
  } 
}
```

```html
<div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="#"></script>
</div>
```

Comment: В моем случае тег `<script>` не имеет id

Comment: Переписал функцию без использования атрибута id в теге script. Просто тогда идентифицировать конкретный script надо будет по значению его атрибута src.

Comment: @Vincent что id, что src - решения равнозначные: всё равно у `<script>` должен быть атрибут с уникальным значением, а сам скрипт должен знать и про атрибут, и про его значение

Comment: @Regent для автора было принципиально не использовать id в теге script, поэтому был использован src в качестве идентификатора.

Comment: смысл в том, чтобы не использовать уникальное значение. У тэга `<scrpt>` нету ни src, ни id